# Exclude a page from rewrite in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Have the standard htaccess for Wordpress

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Am using Wishlist member on this site that requires a Registration URL of 
     http://www.mydomain.com.au/index.php?/register/member

The above htaccess then rewrites it to
     http://www.mydomain.com.au/?/register/member

Hence link does not work.

Trolled everywhere but cannot seem to find a solution.

Any assistance woul dbe greatly appreciated.

Comment: This rewrite doesn't cause that redirect to happen. The redirect is either caused by Wordpress or some other setting in Apache.

Comment: Thanks Sumurai8, will investigate further....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was a Wishlist Member issue.  Resolved by a later update.